# JW Player "doubling" audio in IE

Tags: javascript, flash, flv, jwplayer

I have JW player installed on our site, once on the homepage, and once on our video page. All video's work on the homepage in ALL browsers. However, on the video page, when a video is played in IE, the video starts out correctly, then about 5 - 10 seconds in, the audio portion of the file starts playing a second time, over the top of everything. The original video and audio still play as well, along with the 5-10 second delayed second audio.

The strangest part is I use the same code on both the homepage and video page, I don't understand why it's doing this on only one of the two player instances.

http://www.timetoplaymag.com is the homepage, and the videos are hosted at timetoplaymag . com / video (sorry, it will only let me post 1 link, first time poster).

This current code is using the overlay hosted on longtailvideo.com, as I switched it to see if my own hosted overlay might have been the problem. It's not, as I'm still having problems even with the longtail overlay.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var so = new SWFObject('http://video.anbmedia.com/player/player.swf','mpl','382','216','9');
so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
so.addParam('flashvars','&author=Time to Play&file=http://video.anbmedia.com/<?php echo $video_video; ?>&image=http://images.anbmedia.com/<?php echo $video_image; ?>&autostart=true&skin=http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/overlay.swf&backcolor=000000&frontcolor=FFFFFF&lightcolor=00528e&controlbar=over');
so.write('player');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.
The problem occurs because the player is loaded three times (at least in my case)
However if you set the 'autostart' option to false the other players will not get activated.

Answer (score 0):

Video wont start in either page for me: "Done, but with errors on page". IE 8.0 Windows Vista 64 bit.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to check that too. I've been testing IE7 and IE6, as our users are only about 1% adopted to IE8 (unfortunately)

Comment: Just checked it in Vista 64 with IE 8, "Done, but with errors on page" came up, the video still played though. This is very odd.